# Use ffmpeg on OSX Xcode Project for Mac

Tags: xcode, swift, git, macos, ffmpeg

I am planning to create a new app for personal use on my Mac that uses FFMPEG library, to store a feed from a RTSP IP camera.

Following this [official installation procedure from FFMPEG](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/MacOSX) I have manage to successfully achieve the following 2 steps:

**To get ffmpeg for OS X, you first have to install ​Homebrew. If you don't want to use Homebrew, see the section below.**

- ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL
  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

**Then:**
 - brew install automake fdk-aac git lame libass libtool libvorbis
   libvpx \ opus sdl shtool texi2html theora wget x264 xvid yasm

**Question:**
My question here because I am confused, is how to import a library into Xcode so I can use it in the application I am about to build for my Mac. I can see plenty of GitHub projects related to FFMPEG with IOS/Android, but none for OSX.

All the FFMPEG commands under terminal are working fine, such as converting a video etc.

Answer (score 5):

If you look in `/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg` you will find the actual `ffmpeg` package and everything in `homebrew` is just symbolic links to that. For example:

```
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -> ../Cellar/ffmpeg/3.0.2/bin/ffmpeg
```

Now, if you stay in that directory and do this, you will find all the `pkgconfig` configuration settings for the constituent parts of `ffmpeg`:

```
find . -name \*.pc

./lib/pkgconfig/libavcodec.pc
./lib/pkgconfig/libavdevice.pc
./lib/pkgconfig/libavfilter.pc
./lib/pkgconfig/libavformat.pc
./lib/pkgconfig/libavresample.pc
./lib/pkgconfig/libavutil.pc
./lib/pkgconfig/libpostproc.pc
./lib/pkgconfig/libswresample.pc
./lib/pkgconfig/libswscale.pc
```

That means you can now find the `include` path and `library` paths that you need to put in the Xcode settings. So, for example, if you want the `includes` for `libavutil`, you can do:

```
pkg-config --cflags libavutil
```

and it will tell you:

```
-I/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.0.2/include
```

If you want the `library` settings for `libavfilter`, you can do:

```
pkg-config --libs libavfilter
```

and it will tell you

```
-L/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.0.2/lib -lavfilter
```

So that is how you get the settings for the compiler/linker. Then you need to put them into Xcode, and I have described that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34341219/2836621) - look at the bit with the yellow, red and blue boxes.

Hope that helps. Oh, you need to do:

```
brew install pkg-config
```

first to get the `pkgconfig` binary.

Comment: You are not supposed to run anything under `/usr/local/Cellar` **directly** - that is why everything is symbolically linked from `/usr/local/bin` to the Cellar. The general idea is that you should use the binaries in `/usr/local/bin` by setting your PATH to include that directory.

Comment: hello there, managed to resolve that. I am at the point where I need to compile my ffmpeg library using the XCode command line tool. This is the command used for opencv - g++ $(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv) process.cpp -o process. Can you give me the example I need to add to the terminal for the FFMPEG Library?

Comment: Now I am confused - I understood from your question that you wanted to use Xcode. Xcode is a graphical tool, not command line - which is why I linked to my other post about the settings in the Xcode GUI. And `clang/clang++` is the Apple Xcode compiler, not `gcc/g++` which is GNU.

Comment: This is in the answer you gave me:
Then you need to put them into Xcode, and I have described that here - look at the bit with the yellow, red and blue boxes.

Did everything successfully so far, the only thing left is what to put under 
- Header Search Paths
- Other Linker Flags.    

I am using Swift

Comment: I have no idea - that's the first mention of `swift`! I have added the `swift` tag to your post in the hope that someone else can help you. Sorry.

Comment: Can I just use a bridge and enable my swift project to use objective-c files?

Answer (score 3):

In general, you need to configure the Xcode target build settings to add `/usr/local/include` to the *Header Search Path*.

Then your `#include <ffmpeg.h>` (or whatever it's called) will start to work.

Then for linking to `libffmpeg.a` (or whatever it's called), you can do one of two things:

1. Add the file to the *Additional Libraries and Frameworks* of the build settings (selecting it via a file open dialog).
2. Add `/usr/local/lib` to the *Library Search Paths* and `-lffmpeg` to the *Other Linker Flags*.

(1. is better if you ask me).

I use Macports, so for me the paths are `/opt/local/{include,lib}` however with Homebrew there might be an additional level of directory (like `/usr/local/ffmpeg/{include,lib}`, but you should be able to work that out yourself.

I won't go into details of how to actually use FFMPEG as that is way too involved (and I know nothing about it).

Comment: Hi Sir, Need you serious Help in this Question. Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57952043/how-to-use-ffmpeg-library-in-ios-swift

Answer (score 2):

Although this does not answer the specific question here ("how to import such and such libraries"),

for anyone googling here, these days to use FFmpeg in OSX you just

## Use the famous import script of Kewlbear

which you can easily find here

https://github.com/kewlbear/FFmpeg-iOS-build-script

and which does everything.

It is a huge amount of non-trivial work maintaining such a build script, and fortunately there's someone who does that work on an ongoing basis.

Comment: the script is for iOS and tvOS only. not OSX.