# How to use FFmpeg Library in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, ffmpeg

I have integrated [FFmpeg](https://github.com/kewlbear/FFmpeg-iOS-build-script) Library in Xcode successfully. But I don’t know, how to use it, how to run FFmpeg commands?? If anyone has any example of how to use it. That'd be really appreciated.

I have integrated it by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45613907/adding-ffmpeg-to-our-xcode-projectguide) guide.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What are you intending to do in your app with FFMPEG that you couldnt achieve without it ?

Comment: @SeanLintern  As we are working with Audio/Video, in which we have to merge Video/Audio, merge more then 1 Video and show side by side same like in Tiktok or Smule App, change extension of Audio/Video files etc. Main Functionality that i want to do with it is to merge multiple videos into one.

Comment: Lots of similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+ffmpeg

Comment: @Scriptable Everyone is telling about the integration of the FFmpeg and few of them are telling about Commands…

But no one is telling about HOW TO USE??? Which things i need to import and how do i need to run Command?

Comment: Hmm you can do all of this with the apple AVKit though. But if you have all the FFMPEG scripts that you use for like androird then you can make that code cross compaitable

Comment: @SeanLintern I have tried it using AVKit and maximum of work but some how due to many reasons, now i need ffmpeg for to perform all these above tasks…

Comment: Did you manage to figure out how to use it ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my resolution. I hope it can work for you.
Assuming you has integrated FFmpeg Library in Xcode successfully.

First, Create a header file named "avcodec_shim.h":

```
//avcodec_shim.h
#pragma once
#include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"
```

Second, Create a empty file with a fixed name "module.modulemap":

```
module CFFmpeg [system] {
  module AVCodec {
      header "avcodec_shim.h"
      link "avcodec"
      export *
  }
  module AVFormat {
      header "avformat_shim.h"
      link "avformat"
      export *
  }
  .....
}
```

Third, Go to "TARGET"->"Build Setting", and set "Import Paths" as the **ABSOLUTELY PATH OF FOLDER** containing "module.modulemap" file. ***NOTE: not the file absolutely path.***

Final, Import the module using "import CFFmpeg", and using FFmpeg APIs as usual.