# Getting started with rocksdb on MacOS

Tags: macos, rocksdb

I followed the [guide](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/blob/master/INSTALL.md) and did:

```
brew install rocksdb
```

and I stuck here. What should I do to use `rocksdb`?

I copied the content of [this example file](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/blob/master/examples/c_simple_example.c) and  tried to compile it, both with `gcc-5` (brew) and `gcc` (clang) on Mac OS, but both of them return error. I am using Xcode 7.3.1 on Mac OS 10.11.5.

The error is:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_rocksdb_backup_engine_close", referenced from:
      _main in ccNZ2cWh.o
  "_rocksdb_backup_engine_create_new_backup", referenced from:
      _main in ccNZ2cWh.o
  "_rocksdb_backup_engine_open", referenced from:
      _main in ccNZ2cWh.o
  "_rocksdb_backup_engine_restore_db_from_latest_backup", referenced from:
      _main in ccNZ2cWh.o
  "_rocksdb_close", referenced from:
      _main in ccNZ2cWh.o
  "_rocksdb_get", referenced from:
      _main in ccNZ2cWh.o
  "_rocksdb_open", referenced from:
      _main in ccNZ2cWh.o
  "_rocksdb_options_create", referenced from:
      _main in ccNZ2cWh.o
  "_rocksdb_options_destroy", referenced from:
      _main in ccNZ2cWh.o
  "_rocksdb_options_increase_parallelism", referenced from:
      _main in ccNZ2cWh.o
  "_rocksdb_options_optimize_level_style_compaction", referenced from:
      _main in ccNZ2cWh.o
  "_rocksdb_options_set_create_if_missing", referenced from:
      _main in ccNZ2cWh.o
  "_rocksdb_put", referenced from:
      _main in ccNZ2cWh.o
  "_rocksdb_readoptions_create", referenced from:
      _main in ccNZ2cWh.o
  "_rocksdb_readoptions_destroy", referenced from:
      _main in ccNZ2cWh.o
  "_rocksdb_restore_options_create", referenced from:
      _main in ccNZ2cWh.o
  "_rocksdb_restore_options_destroy", referenced from:
      _main in ccNZ2cWh.o
  "_rocksdb_writeoptions_create", referenced from:
      _main in ccNZ2cWh.o
  "_rocksdb_writeoptions_destroy", referenced from:
      _main in ccNZ2cWh.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**Update:**

After adding rocksdb library to Header and Library Search Path in Xcode as follow:

[image: xcode screenshot]

I tried as on [rocksdb website](http://rocksdb.org/overview/)

```
rocksdb::DB* db;
rocksdb::Options options;
```

and met another problem:

[image: DBOptions problem]

Answer (score 2):

You must tell the linker where the `rocksdb` library is and what it is called so it can find the symbols.

Assuming **homebrew** installed `rocksdb` into `/usr/local/Cellar/rocksdb/4.5.1`, you will probably want something like:

```
gcc-5 -std=c++11 program.c -o program -L /usr/local/Cellar/rocksdb/4.5.1/lib -lrocksdb
```

or, maybe something less version-specific since it is symlinked anyway:

```
gcc-5 -std=c++11 program.c -o program -L /usr/local/lib -lrocksdb
```

If you want to use the Xcode GUI (rather than the command-line), you will need to follow the trail of green, yellow, blue, red things in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34341219/2836621) but fill in the values for `rocksdb` as above.

Comment: Hello @mark-setchell, I updated my question a little bit, could you please take a look?

Comment: You seem to be missing the "red" part of the linked post still - you still need `-lrocksdb` in the `Other Linker Flags` section in Xcode.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot Mark, you saved my day.