# dyld: Library not loaded:Reason: image not found

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I created a new project and i'm using a dynamic library that I downloaded.
I set the header search path to the Include directory where all of the .h files are, and the Library Search Path to where the .dylib files are but i'm still getting the error:

> dyld: Library not loaded:Reason: image not found

Comment: I think you are missing the red bit in the following answer... http://stackoverflow.com/a/34341219/2836621

Comment: I did put the path of the .h files and .dyld files in the locations mentioned, like i said. 
About the linker - how would i know which libraries to put? (i didn't download it using homebrew) If i'm using only one, should i just put it? and is there a need to put 'l' before its name? either way it still doesn't work.. :/

Comment: What is the library you downloaded, and what `.dyld` files are in there? That's what you need to add, I think.

Comment: It's The Foundry's Nuke NDK (Nuke Development Kit) and it has about 30 libraries..

Comment: Maybe this helps... http://tomjbward.co.uk/nuke-example-xcode-project/

Comment: yeah thanks i've seen that but it didn't help either..