# OpenCV - compiler can't find drawKeypoints of features2d.hpp?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to use the drawKeypoints function.
This is how i'm calling it:

```
drawKeypoints( img1, keypoints1, final, color, flags);
```

Where:

```
img1 = my image (Mat)
keypoints = vector<KeyPoint> generated from calling the ORB detector
final = output Mat
color = Scalar::all(-1)
flags = DrawMatchesFlags::DEFAULT;
```

But i get this linking error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::drawKeypoints(cv::_InputArray const&, std::vector<cv::KeyPoint, std::allocator<cv::KeyPoint> > const&, cv::_InputOutputArray const&, cv::Scalar_<double> const&, int)", referenced from:
```

These are my includes:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
```

Why can't my compiler (XCode) find that function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to link against **OpenCV**'s *"opencv_features2d"* library which provides the `cv::drawKeypoints` function.

See the red- and blue-outlined boxes [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34341219/2836621).