# How do I use C libraries installed using Homebrew

Tags: c++, c, homebrew, libgphoto2

I used Homebrew to install gphoto2 and libgphoto2 for use in a camera-control application using C++.  I have confirmed that header files were linked in /usr/local/includes:

[Screencap of includes folder on my system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvT5G.png)

Based on the sample code available at https://github.com/gphoto/libgphoto2/tree/master/examples, it seems like I should be able to use includes such as `#include <gphoto2/gphoto2.h>` to access the header files, but that approach has failed using both Clang and Xcode as the compiler.  The files are not found.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you try making a small program and then compiling it with gcc and then pasting the output here...Also try using ls or similar command to see if the file is accesible or not..

Comment: Are you compiling in Terminal or in XCode? In Terminal you need `clang -I/usr/local/include ...`

Comment: See this post - specifically the blue box http://stackoverflow.com/a/34341219/2836621

Comment: Thanks a million Mark, that did the trick!