# How to install OpenCV for C++ on Mac and configure with Netbeans

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, netbeans

I am having trouble trying to install OpenCV correctly and configure it with Netbeans.

One of my University units is using Visual Studio with OpenCV but I do not own a Windows PC so need to install OpenCV on my Mac OSX 10.12.3 and configure it to work with netbeans in a C++ project.

I have explored many avenues to do this but can't seem to come to a solution.

If someone could provide a step by step guide, that would be very helpful. Ideally I would like the most recent version of OpenCV.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

Install **Oracle VirtualBox** for free on your Mac and then install Windows in a virtual machine. It is a single file on your Mac so you can remove all that ugly Microsoft stuff as soon as you finish your class. You can run the virtual machine at the same time as macOS (it is not dual boot and doesn't mess with your boot sector) and copy and paste between the two, share files between the two and use networking from the virtual machine.

**Option 2**

Get a free Amazon EC2 Windows instance and run your OpenCV and NetBeans on there. You can connect from home using RDP from your Mac and also from school so your work is always accessible.

**Option 3**

Install **homebrew** on your Mac, then install **OpenCV** and **NetBeans** with

```
brew install opencv
brew install Caskroom/cask/netbeans
```

Then configure the two to work together as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34341219/2836621).